# Adding a column to an existing table in Node.js & Knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, backend, knex.js

I'm using Node.js and Knex to build a service for my router. However, I can't figure out how to add a column to an existing table, any help would be appreciated.
Also, I'm using PostgreSQL, but I don't think that matters for the question.

So, this is what I have for adding rows to the table:

```js
insertData(knex, table, row) {
  return knex
    .insert(row)
    .into(table)
    .returning('*')
    .then(rows => {
      return rows[0];
    });
}
```

I'm guessing adding a column to the table would be something similar to this? I just can't figure out/find the solution.

Answer (score 26):

**For migrations:**

This was taken from this [article](https://dev.to/cesareferrari/knex-migrations-5hkb?signin=true)

1. First make a migration:

`knex migrate:make add_new_column_to_table`

2. then in the migration update the file to:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.table('<table name>', table => {
    table.string('<new column name>', 128);
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.table('<table name>', table => {
    table.dropColumn('<new column name>');
  })
};
```

3. then run the migration:

`knex migrate:latest`

Answer (score 10):

The answers above are correct EXCEPT...

Make sure to write "knex.schema.**alterTable**" instead of "knex.schema.table".

Below is correct:

```
 return knex.schema.alterTable('<table name>', table => {
    table.dropColumn('<new column name>');
  })
```

Comment: Both are correct as one is an alias of the other. `alterTable` is more explicit. See https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3990.

Answer (score 6):

you should use Schema Building function provided by Knex.js

Below is an example from [its official documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-table):

```
//Chooses a database table, and then modifies the table

knex.schema.table('users', function (table) {
  table.string('first_name');
  table.string('last_name');
})

//Outputs:
//alter table `users` add `first_name` varchar(255), add `last_name` varchar(255);
```

Answer (score 2):

1.run this :

> knex migrate:make add_new_column_to_table

2.a new file will be created **'20220524120511_dd_new_column_to_table.js'**

use this code :

```
exports.up = async function (knex) {
    await knex.schema.table("table_name", (table) => {
    table.string("column_name", 128);
  });
};

exports.down = async function (knex) {
    await knex.schema.table("table_name", (table) => {
    table.dropColumn("column_name");
  });
};
```

3. run this :

> knex migrate:latest